# Has a Two Key TDES encryption ever been successfully attacked?

Tags: des, 3des, attack

Is there any known instance of a Two Key TDES ever being successfully attacked (in real life), when the key is used to encrypt less than $2^{20}$ words?

Comment: Also: $\:$ "Is there any ... ever being" _used_ in real life? $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 4):

If we talk about key search attacks (rather than key compromise or/and side-channel attacks), the answer must be **no**, for [the best known method is impractical](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2466/555).

On the other hand there has been numerous successful key-recovery attacks against devices using TDES, including on some that try hard to avoid it. One example [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mkb23/research/Thesis.pdf), another [there](http://www.emsec.rub.de/research/publications/desfire_ches_2011/).