# Does a 128bit 3DES need billions of years to decrypt using brute force attack?

Tags: 3des

a) I did some research and there are two opinions.. some say it cracks in several years and others say it doesn't crack for billions of years USING BRUTE FORCE ATTACK...

Comment: 3DES doesn't use 128bit key.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. i am studying information security and there is a case exercise in the book where it says that a person used 128 bit 3DES key to encrypt the message.

Comment: Then your book is wrong. There is no 128bit 3DES variant, only 56, 112 and 168bit variants. Also time spent bruteforcing is always same [bound] for same size of key= 2^keysize. So your calculations like 64bit*2 are incorrect.

Comment: 128-bit triple-DES actually has a 112-bit key because the 16 parity bits are ignored (or deducible from the others), and no more than 111-bit resistance (assuming chosen plaintext) due to the complementation property; see [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2466/555) about its resistance to better attacks. 128-bit double-DES (not triple) is vulnerable to [meet-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack), and better attacks needing much less memory.

Comment: The reason @fgrieu mentions double DES is that is what you have described (encrypt with key 1, decrypt with key 2).  Triple DES, or 3DES, is _typically_ an encrypt-decrypt-encrypt operation with 2 keys for a total of 112 bits of key material.  If you + your hardware can make X tests a year then it will take $2^{111} / X$ years on average to break.

Comment: @fgrieu How much time to crack that 128 bit triple DES? Is it billions?

Comment: @VodafoneSmart I don't want to sound insulting, but please slow down, read, and think more than knee-jerk respond.  Quoting from above "There is no 128bit 3DES variant".  If this is homework I suggest you note that in your answer then make your computation for the 112 bits instead of 128.  Being up-front is usually best with graders and professors.