# What is the importance of superencryption?

Tags: encryption, aes, keys, des, 3des

Please, can any extensively explain the importance of super encryption in relation to attacks experienced by single standard algorithms

Comment: By "super encryption" do you mean cascaded (multiple) symmetric encryption, i.e. using multiple symmetric ciphers with independent keys to encrypt data? In that case, in general [a cascade is as difficult to break as the first cipher, and the latter ciphers don't necessarily add any security](https://www.isiweb.ee.ethz.ch/archive/massey_pub/pdf/BI434.pdf). Of course the details matter, and the latter ciphers *can* allow it to be as difficult to break as the strongest cipher (and the weaker ones don't add any security). Because of this we usually just use the strongest cipher and dump the rest.

Comment: Yes, I meant multiple encryption. But can superencryption help in solving the problem of bruteforce?

Comment: This site is Q/A questions only, soliciting for personal advice is not considered proper.

Comment: From a single-user perspective, it's unnecessary. However, double encryption provides [better](https://youtu.be/pVlFiijo77g) multi-user security. Generally though, nobody bothers with multiple encryption, especially since it's much slower and more complicated to implement alongside what @SAIPeregrinus said.

Comment: Nothing in modern Cryptography [AES-256 is enough for all](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76746/18298)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a strong cipher like AES, there is no need to cascade it. The only reason to cascade is if the cipher has a small key size and silly federal regulations demand that you keep using it. In that case, you can increase the effective keysize. This is the case with [3DES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/51632/54184), although note that such constructions are weakened by a [meet-in-the-middle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/6346/54184) that drops keyspace from $2^{168}$ to $2^{112}$.

If you can use a cipher that's *already* secure, there's no reason to cascade multiple ciphers.